# Find XPath with known value using c#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am attempting to write an automated smoketest for an internal corporate website using c# and Selenium Webdriver.

The problem is that the website is dynamically generated using a lot of Dojo Javascript. It also contains frames and popups. o_O

So everytime the page is loaded the normal element attributes are randomized and will never consistently be the same.

The order is also randomized.

The ONLY known constant is the INNER text contained within these tags.

**Example 1 (Initial Page Load):**

```html
<div id="23">
  <span id="Random40">KNOWN TEXT ONE</span>
  <span id="Random41">KNOWN TEXT TWO</span>
  <span id="Random42">KNOWN TEXT THREE</span>
</div>
```

**Example 2 (Subsequent Page Load):**

```html
<div id="Random 11">
  <span id="Random45">KNOWN TEXT THREE</span>
  <span id="Random46">KNOWN TEXT ONE</span>
  <span id="Random43">KNOWN TEXT TWO</span>
</div>
```

As you can see in the examples above:

1. The element IDs are randomized.
2. The order that the INNER text inside the span tags is randomized.
3. The INNER text inside the span tags is consistently the same.

With everything being randomized and the order changing how can I programatically parse the DOM, find the text value, and then determine the XPath once found?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the text could be enough since, once you found an element by text:

```
//span[. = "KNOWN TEXT ONE"]
```

you can go up, down and sideways using [different axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes).

Comment: This works in Firebug using Firepath, when I type that in, it navigates to the proper node. In c# it fails saying it "Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//td[. = 'Account Address Book - Sample']\"}"}"

Answer (score 0):

driver.findelement(By.cssseector("div:firt-child")).cick();

It will chose first element 
eg: it will choose 'KNOWN TEXT ONE'

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[./span[contains(text(), 'KNOWN TEXT ONE')]][./span[contains(text(), 'KNOWN TEXT TWO')]][./span[contains(text(), 'KNOWN TEXT THREE')]]
```

If you're navigating between frames you need to switch to the frame containing the nodes first before you can see it.  You also need to put a short sleep or implicit wait after switching to the Frame because Selenium doesn't wait for the actual frame switch to occur.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("Frame Name");
Thread.Sleep(100);
```